# Crashing error after cleaning up after saving FBO to camera roll? Swift 2.0 selector syntax

Tags: ios, swift, buffer

So I have this code to save a currently bound FBO to the camera roll. The first part of this code works perfectly! If I dont try to clean up the buffer or image reference everything works fine, and a picture is placed inside of the camera roll. Unfortunately there is a 4mb memory leak as a result.

So apparently I need to clean up some of the data.

The first place I thought to look was my `var buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<GLubyte>(nil)` the problem is that if you clear that right after the `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` call you get a really odd crashing error with no stack trace that makes sense.

So I figure that it takes time for the data to save to the photo album as such I need to use a completion selector. The problem is I have tried a couple different ways of using the selector block but every time I get a crash and a message from "NSForwarding" in this case I get:

```
NSForwarding: warning: object 0x16e6bb60 of class 'App.ScreenshotSaving' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[App.ScreenshotSaving methodSignatureForSelector:]
```

For the reference this class is instantiated inside of a static class like so

```
class Storage
{
    static var ssave = ScreenshotSaving()
}
```

and as such when its time to take a screenshot `Storage.ssave.saveScreenshot()` is called.

```
import Foundation
import GLKit
import OpenGLES
import Fabric


class ScreenshotSaving
{
    var myImage = UIImage()
    var buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<GLubyte>(nil)
    func saveScreenshot()
    {
        var width:GLint = 0
        var height:GLint = 0

        glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH), &width)
        glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT), &height)

        let mdl:Int = Int(width * height * 4)
        buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<GLubyte>(malloc(Int(mdl)))

        glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GLenum(GL_RGBA), GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE), buffer)

        let provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(nil, buffer, mdl, nil)


        let bitsPerComponent:Int = 8
        let bitsPerPixel:Int = 32
        let bytesPerRow:Int = 4 * Int(width)

        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bitmapInfo:CGBitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: 0 << 12)
        let renderIntent = CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault

        let imageRef = CGImageCreate(Int(width), Int(height), bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo, provider, nil, false, renderIntent)

        FabricI.crashLog("Save screenshot: Finished image ref")

        myImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef!)

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImage, self, #selector(ScreenshotSaving.finishedPic), nil)
    }


    @objc func finishedPic()
    {
        myImage = UIImage()
        free(buffer)
    }
}
```

One more question, when the photo is saved to the photo album is it compressed like a regular image or will it be the same size as the raw data?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you make `ScreenshotSaving` subclass `NSObject`?

Comment: I'd also be curious to see if not subclassing `NSObject` and instead using `dynamic` instead of `@objc` for `finishedPic()` works

Comment: @BenKane That does not work however it does cause a new crashing error                  "2016-08-26 00:07:22.224 Trillium[5461:1043289] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSInvocation setArgument:atIndex:]: index (2) out of bounds [-1, 1]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x259db91b 0x25176e17 0x2590647f 0x2da45a31 0x2da463e7 0x2d4c718b 0xb76b7f 0xb76b6b 0xb7b655 0x2599db6d 0x2599c067 0x258eb229 0x258eb015 0x26edbac9 0x29fbf189 0xaf668 0x25593873)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Comment: Does changing `@objc` to `dynamic` stop the crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current crash is because your class isn't a subclass of `NSObject`, so it doesn't know how to find the target method (func).

I see you already tried that in the comments. The crash when you try that is because the selector has specific requirements in this case. The method signature for the selector must match (the form of):

```
- (void)image: (UIImage *) image didFinishSavingWithError: (NSError *) error contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo
```

The name can be different but it must take 3 parameters with those types.

```
func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo:Un
```